# Can someone correct me on how I got this answer wrong (finding equation from exponential graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I'm aware its pretty basic but when trying to find the equation from [Graph] I worked out the equation to be $f(x)=2.5e^{-3.598x}+20$ just using basic algebra but I looked at the answer and it (the "a" value) was listed as being $1.4$ (final equation $f(x)=2.5e^{-1.4x}+20$)

How did they get this? Can someone point me in the right direction as to calculate my own "a" variable I substituted the x and y data points given (see graph):

$20.616=2.5e^{a(1)}+20$

Its just one of those stupid mistakes that you make but its really annoying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=2.5e^{-ax}+20$, then $f(1)=2.5e^{-a}+20$. But you want to have $f(1)=20.616$. And\begin{align}f(1)=20.616&\iff2.5e^{-a}+20=20.616\\&\iff e^{-a}=\frac{0.616}{2.5}=0.2464\\&\iff a\approx1.4.\end{align}

Comment: Oh, yeah, that checks out, thanks dude

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX FYI voting the answer up and accepting it is a "better thanks".

Comment: Cant do it yet, need more reputation

Comment: You cannot upvote, but anybody can accept an answer to one of their questions.

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX Ok, let me upvote your question. Now you can.