# Can somebody tell me why this value has changed for exponential functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

In the exponential equation $f(x)=2.5e^{−1.4x}+20$ worked out from the graph below   (original form: $f(x)=be^{-ax}+c$) why is the $b$ value listed as $2.5$ even if the coordinates for the y intercept are given as $(0,22.5)$? Shouldnt the $b$ value also be $22.5$? Why has it changed and how did it change?
[image]

Comment: You have $f(0)=b+c$ , not $f(0)=b$

Comment: I still dont understand?

Comment: $f(0) = 2.5 e^{-1.4 \cdot 0} + 20 = 2.5 \cdot e^0 + 20 = 2.5 + 20 = 22.5$ It checks out.

Comment: Youz have $f(0)=22.5=2.5+20$ and $b=22.5$ would imply $f(0)=b$

Comment: But why did it change to 2.5?

Comment: So its related to the asymptote?

Comment: $f(0) = 22.5$ on the graph. Now $f(x)=be^{-ax}+c$ and as $x$ goes to infinity $f(x)$ goes to $c$ and from the graph this $c$ value is 20. So now $f(x)=be^{-ax}+20$. When $x=0$ you have $f(0) =22.5=be^{-a.0}+20=b+20$ so that $b = 22.5-20=2.5$

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX Please do not make edits to the question which invalidate the posted comments and answers. Rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=be^{-ax}+c$

Now, when $x \to \infty$, the value of the function tend to $20$.
Thus, $c=20$. ( as $\lim_{ x \to \infty} e^{-x} =0$)

Also,from graph we can infer that the value of the function at $x=0$ is $22.5$. Thus, on substituting $x=0$, we get $f(0) \implies be^{-1.4 \cdot 0} + 20 \implies b e^0 + 20 = 22.5\implies b=2.5$

For finding out $a$, you can use the fact that $f(1)=20.616$ (already answered in your other question [Can someone correct me on how I got this answer wrong (finding equation from exponential graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4394355/1012971))

Thus, $f(x)=2.5e^{−1.4x}+20
$